# What is it.isAny and what is it.is in Unit mock testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, moq

There are many questions that have been already asked on this but I think I need something more basic that could clear this concept as I am beginner in TDD. I can't go forward till then.

Could you please go through following testmethod and explain if I have wrong understanding:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldSearch()
{
         var ColumnList = new List<Column>();
```

The below line means that I am mocking object.

But what this `It.IsAny<>()` means here?

```
 this.ColumnServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetColumn(It.IsAny<Context>(), It.IsAny<Column>()))
                       .Returns(ColumnList);

 var result = this.getColouminfo.GetFinalRecords(this.context, this.gridColumn);

 this.ColumnServiceMock.Verify(x => x.GetColumn(It.Is<Context>(y => y == this.context),
 It.Is<Column>(y => y.Id == 2)), Times.Once);

  Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Data.Count, "Not equal");

  Assert.IsTrue(result.Data.Success, "No success");
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`It.IsAny<T>` is checking that the parameter is of type T, it can be any instance of type T. It's basically saying, I don't care what you pass in here as long as it is type of T.

```
this.ColumnServiceMock
    .Setup(x => x.GetColumn(It.IsAny<Context>(), It.IsAny<Column>()))
    .Returns(ColumnList);
```

The above is saying whenever the `GetColumn` method is called with any parameters (as long as they are type of `Context` and `Column` respectively), return the `ColumnList`.

`It.Is<T>` allows you to inspect what was passed in and determine if the parameter that was passed in meets your needs.

```
this.ColumnServiceMock
    .Verify(
        x => x.GetColumn(It.Is<Context>(y => y == this.context), It.Is<Column>(y => y.Id == 2)),
        Times.Once);
```

The above is asserting that the `GetColumn` method was called exactly once with the `Context` parameter equal to `this.Context` and a `Column` parameter whose Id property equals 2.

Edit: Revisiting this answer years later with some more knowledge.

```
this.ColumnServiceMock
    .Verify(
        x => x.GetColumn(It.Is<Context>(y => y == this.context), It.Is<Column>(y => y.Id == 2)),
        Times.Once);
```

can be shortened to

```
this.ColumnServiceMock
    .Verify(
        x => x.GetColumn(this.context, It.Is<Column>(y => y.Id == 2)),
        Times.Once);
```

You don't need to use It.Is to check for reference equality, you can just pass the object directly.

Comment: In context with your answer, When we create setup using mock and we are saying that GetColumn will be called with any instance of Context and any instance of Column, at the same time does this statement make a call to "GetColoum" method?

Comment: The call to Setup doesn't call the method, it simply ensures that when that method is called at some point in the future, it will return the value you expect. Say for example you have a repository with a GetData method that goes to a database and returns some rows, and a controller that has a dependency on the repository and formats the data. If you are testing the controller, you don't want to connect to the database so you create a mock repository and call Setup to make sure that your GetData method returns some sample data for the controller to consume.

Comment: Thank You v.mch :)

Answer (score 20):

`It.IsAny<T>()` specifies anything thats of that type.

`It.Is<T>()` is more specific and takes a lamda to make sure it matches that exactly.

Both are just ways to specify an argument that you don't want to specify exactly when mocking. So for example if the argument is a string name and you don't care about the exact name in your test you can use:

`It.IsAny<string>()` in your mock specification, which will match any string.

If you always want the name to begin with "S" then you can do

`It.Is<string>(x => x.StartsWith("S"))` which will only match strings starting with S.

Comment: I am afraid that the last line should be: It.Is<string>(x => x.StartsWith("S"))